# Postgres array fields: find where array contains value

Tags: postgresql

Currently I have a table schema that looks like this:

```
| id | visitor_ids |      name      |
|----|-------------|----------------|
|  1 | {abc,def}   | Chris Houghton |
|  2 | {ghi}       | Matt Quinn     |
```

The `visitor_ids` are all GUIDs, I've just shortened them for simplicity.

A user can have **multiple** visitor ids, hence the array type.

I have a GIN index created on the `visitor_ids` field.

I want to be able to lookup users by a visitor id. Currently we're doing this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE visitor_ids && array['abc'];
```

The above works, but it's really really slow at scale - it takes around 45ms which is ~700x slower than a lookup by the primary key. (Even with the GIN index)

Surely there's got to be a more efficient way of doing this? I've looked around and wasn't able to find anything.

Possible solutions I can think of could be:

- The current query is just bad and needs improving
- Using a separate user_visitor_ids table
- Something smart with special indexes

Help appreciated :)

Comment: try your second solution and report back to us.

Comment: Definitely, the second solution it what I would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the second solution - 700x faster. Bingo.

I feel like this is an unsolved problem however, what's the point in adding arrays to Postgres when the performance is so bad, even with indexes?

Comment: Just because they are there doesn't mean you have to (ab)use them for everything and denormalize all 1:many relationships with arrays. If you e.g. store a list of values that you don't search and you always access as "one thing" then an array might actually be better than having a 1:many relationship with two tables.

Comment: There's no abuse here - what this has demonstrated is that Postgres arrays are completely useless for lookups over millions of rows, even with GIN indexes.